# calculate sum of a column after groupby based on unique values of second column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe`, where there are columns like `gp1, gp2, gp3, id, sub_id, activity`

```
usr gp2 gp3 id  sub_id  activity
1   IN  ASIA    1   1   1
1   IN  ASIA    1   2   1
1   IN  ASIA    2   9   0
2   IN  ASIA    3   4   1
2   IN  ASIA    3   5   1
2   IN  ASIA    4   6   1
2   IN  ASIA    4   7   0
2   IN  ASIA    4   8   0
```

I want to aggregate the above dataframe by grouping on `usr, gp1, gp2`, and calculate two columns one is 'Account (id)', which is number of unique `id` for every group & then Actuals (Activity) which is `Activity` based on every unique 'id'.

`for example, if id = 1, the activity sum would be 1 not 2`

```
usr gp1 gp3 id  Activity
1   IN  ASIA    2   1
2   IN  ASIA    2   2

df.groupby(['usr', 'gp2', 'gp3']).agg({'id': pd.Series.nunique, 'activity': LOGIC_REQUIRED})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy.apply` to operate on multiple (dependent) columns:

```
df.drop(columns='sub_id').groupby(['usr', 'gp2', 'gp3'])\
    .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'id': [x['id'].nunique()],
                                   'activity': [x[x.activity.ne(0)].drop_duplicates(subset='id')['activity'].sum()]})
           .set_index('id')).reset_index()
```

---

```
   usr gp2   gp3  id  activity
0    1  IN  ASIA   2         1
1    2  IN  ASIA   2         2
```

Comment: @RomanPerehkrest - `x.drop_duplicates()` it will drop the the duplicates based on `group by` columns. we need to drop duplicates based on `id` after `groupby`. may be the example i shared doesn;t show that, but i did write this in the question itself.

Comment: after groupby, we need to consider only one `activity` for every `id`.

Comment: @ggupta, *we need to drop duplicates based on id* - yes, see my update

Comment: yeah, but the point is we need to keep the one which has Activity as 1, if anyone don't have 1, then 0.

Comment: very clean and simple approach. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'usr':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
          'gp2':['IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN', 'IN'],
          'gp3':['ASIA', 'ASIA', 'ASIA', 'ASIA', 'ASIA', 'ASIA', 'ASIA', 'ASIA'],
          'id':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
          'sub_id':[1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
          'activity':[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],          
          })

df = (df.groupby(['usr', 'gp2', 'gp3'])
        .agg({'id':'nunique'})
        .reset_index(level=['usr', 'gp2', 'gp3'])
        )
df['Activity'] = df.groupby(['usr', 'gp2', 'gp3']).ngroup().add(1)
```

```
   usr gp2   gp3  id  Activity
0    1  IN  ASIA   2         1
1    2  IN  ASIA   2         2
```